# Change context/uri for sails app

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to host multiple sails application with a single domain.

Using nginx as reverse proxy and trying to route requests to the sails backend. Is there a way to change the default context/uri  of the sails application from "/" to something like "/sample" , "/sample1" ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change nginx configuration like this :

```
location /you_app_dir {
   proxy_pass     http://your_domain.com/;
   proxy_redirect http://your_domain.com/sample;
   port_in_redirect off;
}
```

and define sample route in  your routes.js :

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/smaple': {
    controller: 'default',
    action: 'index'
  }
}
```